# FormData() append - Receive only empty objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, form-data

I started a new project and had never issues to append data to FormData and sending it to the backend. Currently, I receive only empty objects in the backend. What am I missing here?

`this.first_name` is not empty if I console.log it. That's not the problem here.

```js
async createAgent() {
      const data = new FormData()
      data.append('first_name', this.first_name)
      // data.append('last_name', this.last_name)
      // data.append('phone', this.phone)
      // data.append('email', this.email)
      // data.append('languages', this.checkedLanguage)
      // data.append('image', this.selectedFile)

      try {
        const post = await this.$axios.$post('/api/create-agent', data)
    }
```

**Node.js**

```js
exports.createAgent = async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.first_name);
  console.log(req.body);
};
```

**Console Output**

```
undefined
{}
```

**index.js** (Node.js)

```js
const app = express();

app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

[image: Headers]

[image: Payload]

Comment: Hi, are you aware [about this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log#logging_objects)? Also, what do you see in your network tab (from the frontend to the backend)?

Comment: Hi Kissu, I've read about it, but even then I get an empty answer. Or when I want to save the data in the database, nothing arrives there. I don't notice anything unusual in the Network tab. But I am not a pro :-) I added some images

Comment: The client side code looks fine. It's on the backend side. Do you have those middlewares? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296402/8816585

Comment: Yes, I'm using express with bodyparser. But I see since express v4.16.0, you don't have to use bodyparser? Currently, I'm using express v4.18.1

Comment: Double check your version and try with it to be sure.

Comment: I tried it without bodyParser ... and ... with express downgrading + bodyparser.  Both didn't work :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `body-parser`'s docs:

> This does not handle multipart bodies, due to their complex and typically large nature.

which in your screenshot, on the Request Headers part, is stated.

Solutions in your example are:

- just send a JSON payload (parsed by `bodyParser.json()`)
- set Content-Type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (parsed by `bodyParser.urlencoded()`)
- use the recommended modules for multipart body in the docs:

Docs: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/tree/1.20.0#readme

To send a JSON payload with `axios` which you are using in the OP, do:

```
axios.post({
  first_name: "This is a JSON property"
})
```

or

```
$axios.$post()
```

which **IF you're using `nuxt/axios`**, is a convenient function that will return the response body instead of the whole response.

Docs: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage#-shortcuts